# I'm getting an operational error in django administration in access records only

Tags: python, django, django-models

I get this error:

[image: Operational error]

What changes should I do to remove this error?

This is the code I wrote in the `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name



class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)
```

Comment: Did you run the migrations?

Comment: `./manager.py makemigration` and next `./manager.py migrate` ?

Comment: yes, I did @ThierryLathuille

Comment: yes, I did @furas

Answer (score 0):

I think you are useing wrong model name in views.py , Use dj_app.AccessRecord.data in views in state of dj_app_accessrecord.data in views.py

Comment: '''
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    my_dict = {'insert_content':"Hello I'm from dj_app"}
    return render(request,'dj_app/index.html',context=my_dict)
'''